# Solving inequalities involving absolute values

Tags: calculus, functions, inequality, absolute-value, maxima-minima

Find all $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$

$$\max_{x\in[0,1]} |ax+b-x-1| < 1/2$$

I am confused about how to solve absolute value inequality with max function so I don't know how to start solving this problem.

Comment: Do what is always done with absolute values: look at it piecewise.

Comment: @MichaelHardy So is it okay to write the inequality as $ -1/2 < max_{x∈[0,1]} ax+b−x−1 <1/2$

Comment: That would be right if it had said $\displaystyle \left| \max_{x\in[0,1]} (ax+b-x-1) \right|,$ but it said the maximum of the absolute value, not the absolute value of the maximum. $\qquad$

Comment: Also, notice my typesetting correction to the question. Specifically $\displaystyle \max_{x\in[0,1]}$ rather than $\displaystyle max_{x\in[0,1]}. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Ok I noticed the typo but I still couldn't figure out how to look at this piecewise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just square to eliminate the absolute value. It is equivalent to solve for
$$\underset{0\le x\le 1}{\max}(ax+b-x-1)^2<\frac14.$$
Now $\;p(x)=(ax+b-x-1)^2\,$ is a quadratic polynomial and its maximum on $[0,1]$ is one of $p(0)$, $p(1)$. Hence the inequation in absolute value is equivalent to the system of inequations:
$$\begin{cases}
p(0)=(b-1)^2<\dfrac14,\\
p(1)=(a+b-2)^2<\dfrac14, 
\end{cases}\iff\begin{cases} |b-1|<\dfrac12,\\|a+b-2|<\dfrac12, \end{cases}
\iff\begin{cases} \dfrac12<b<\dfrac32,\\\dfrac32<a+b<\dfrac52. \end{cases}$$ 
These inequalities can be solved graphically in the $(a$,$b)$-plane. They're the points inside a parallelogram.

Comment: how do we know its maximum is on one of p(0),p(1) instead of e.g. p(1/2)

Comment: Because, depending on whether the minimum (which is $0$) is attained before $0$, between $0$ and $1$, or after $1$,  $p(x)$  is respectively  increasing, decreasing then increasing, or decreasing on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Pumpkin: Oh! And there's a shorter reason : this quadratic function is *convex*, so $f((1-t)\cdot0+t\cdot 1)=f(t)\le (1-t)f(0)+tf(1)\le \max\bigl(f(0),f(1)\bigr)$ for all $0\le t\le 1$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT.- The line $y=(a-1)x+(b-1)$ determines the absolute value $$\max_{x\in[0,1]} |ax+b-x-1|$$

Consider the square region determined by the points $$A(0,-\dfrac12),B=(1,-\dfrac12),C=(1,\dfrac12),D=(0,\dfrac12)$$ The solution is formed by the couples $(a,b)$ such that the lines $y=(a-1)x+(b-1)$   cut the two vertical sides $AD$ and $BC$ of the square excepting the four extremes $A,B,C$ and $D$. All other line gives
$$\max_{x\in[0,1]} |ax+b-x-1|\ge\dfrac12$$ as it is easy to prove.